# How do I find missing elements in an integer list?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to use a template to find missing numbers, something like this:

```
using type = find_arg_not_in_pack<Range<1, 5>, 1, 2, 4, 5>;
```

And the result should be a pack holding all the numbers that aren't in the arguments provided after the range. In this case it should be something like `pack<3>`. `pack` is like a tuple for non-type parameters, particularly integers. How can one do this?

Comment: I bet it's possible, C++ template metaprogramming being Turing-complete and all, but it'll likely take reams of impenetrable code. What do you feel you need this for, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's just a task I thought of.

Comment: It seems to be possible to get what you have asked about in c++11. Read about metaprogramming and variadic templates.

Comment: Do you assume only positive integers in this list ? Are they necessarily sorted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some type-list machinery for the result, your `pack`, and specialize `find_arg_not_in_pack` for the case where start of range is identical to first argument, with the result definition recursing on the rest of the argument list.